# How can i configure nginx in such a way that it will only allow requests from mobile devices and some restricted IPS

Tags: nginx

How can i configure nginx in such a way that it will only allow requests from mobile devices and some restricted IPS

I wanted to configure it in such a way that it will deny all the requests from browers but for some specific IPs and all mobile devices

Answer (score 0):

You may look for user agent.
See http://alvinalexander.com/technology/nginx-redirect-mobile-devices-users-mobile-website